# Using Collection<String> fooCollection = new ArrayList<String> why this is a bad practise

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have the following simple question. Why is the usage of this:

```
Collection<String> something = new ArrayList<>();
```

Considered a bad practice?

My thoughts are the following:

1. This is opening the scope quite a lot without this being needed.
2. The actual assigned implementation (this case an ArrayList) does not
   logically match the Collection (a list more or less means an ordered
   data structure, whereas a collection not).

Does anyone have any other idea as to why this is not OK?

Comment: *Considered a bad practice* **by who?** *The actual assigned implementation (this case an ArrayList) does not logically match the Collection*. **What?**

Comment: I thought this was generally considered _good_ practise!

Comment: for me, it is completely ok if you are only going to need the `Collection` functionalities

Comment: Agree with Michael.  We're missing a lot of context here.  The scope is not apparent at all, so it might be fine.  Normally coding to an interface (`Collections`) is considered good practice.

Comment: The general "code to an interface" principle would actually suggest this is a **good** practice. I generally tend to narrow down a little to `List` instead of `Collection`, as long as I know the collection type will always be the same. But all this is mostly opinionated talk.

Comment: In general I even prefer to hide as much of the actual implementation as possible. This gives you the most flexibility when it comes to changing your program afterwards or adding features and so on. So for me your code is completely okay and even preferable. I mean as long as you don't need, for example, `RandomAccess` (which `Collection` in general doesn't provide). You should always use the type you need.

Comment: I saw this in a small code snippet written by a colleague a few years ago. Let me provide the context around it. This was a simple static helper method meant to provided just two string values in a list.

I'm familiar with the 'programming to an interface' principle, but isn't a bit too broad for the context in question? A List would have sufficed in my opinion.

Comment: That is as a variable and as the return type in this case.

Comment: @Aris right, so the caller shouldn't have to care that the entries are returned in an abstract `List<>` or even a concrete `ArrayList<>`.   The fact it's been written as `Collection<String>` indicates that order doesn't matter either.

Comment: @Alnitak Well that was the thing, part of my question aside from the fact (as mentioned above) that this broadens up the variable scope for no specific reason, two out of 5 callers of this were actually sorting the returned value prior to doing anything with it.

Comment: @Aris sorted based on what criteria?   Could the function have done that sorting for them (perhaps without "sorting" at all, but simply by adding the elements into the collection in the natural order in which they were generated) ?

Comment: @Alnitak it could have and in all circumstances it would have made the callers not required to perform any sorting (something that I did when visiting that area) amongst other changes (one being to use a List<>)

Comment: @Aris right, so the potential problem is that've programmed to _too generic_ an interface.  They should probably have programmed to `List<String>` instead of `Collection<String>`, but even then it'd be considered good practise to use that interface (`List`) instead of the concrete implementation (`ArrayList<String>`)

Comment: @Alnitak sure and that what was my initial thought when posting this question (not wanting to start a flame war or anything)..My concern was, as you mention that the scope was wayyyy to broad too in this particular example. 

Under no circumstances did I mention that one needed to program to the concrete implementation.

My question is the following though. Apart from the too generic pattern here, are there any other potential side-effects in this (that is being too generic)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this counts as an opinion-based question, which isn't normally allowed on Stack Overflow. But while it's still open, I'll take the opportunity to give my own opinion:

It's not bad practice. You want to limit the interface as much as possible for clients. If a client doesn't need ArrayList methods, don't provide them. If a client shouldn't "know" what specific collection type it is, don't tell it. This will help leave the option for switching to a different kind of collection in the future.

Comment: _"I think this counts as an opinion-based question, which isn't normally allowed"_ - so you should comment, and vote to close.  At the very least, go for Community Wiki so you're not accused of rep-harvesting.

Comment: What's rep-harvesting?

Comment: I'd say for parameters and return types, use the most generic interface type available. For local variables or private fields, I usually use the most specific interface, i.e. `List`, `Set`, or `Map`.

Comment: @aetheria there used to be an impolite term for it here but it's not permitted any more.  The practise of answering trivial low-hanging fruit questions just to collect rep.

Comment: @Michael, Yes, I guess it's rare that the local code wouldn't care which type of collection it is.

Comment: Alnitak, tbh I don't care about rep. I've voted to close though as per your instructions.